# How to configure Texstudio to use PythonTeX?

Tags: texstudio, pythontex

I learned how to add User commands to TeXstudio here: http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html

In particular, for PythonTeX, I added the following command: [image]

Then, I formed my build and view like so:

[image]

```
txs:///pdflatex | txs:///pythontex | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///biber | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view-pdf-internal
```

I have confirmed that `pythontex.exe` is known to the system, by simply running the command in a console and noting the following output:

```
usage: pythontex.py [-h] [--version] [--encoding ENCODING]
                    [--error-exit-code {true,false}] [--runall [{true,false}]
                    | --rerun {never,modified,errors,warnings,always}]
                    [--hashdependencies [{true,false}]] [-j N] [-v]
                    [--interpreter INTERPRETER]
                    [--debug [<family>:<session>:<restart>] | --interactive
                    [<family>:<session>:<restart>]]
                    TEXNAME
pythontex.py: error: too few arguments
C:\texlive\2016\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:679: command failed with exit code 2:
python.exe c:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\scripts\pythontex\pythontex.py
```

So, I decided to try my setup out on a simple document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
print(r'\begin{center}')
print(r'\textit{A message from Python!}')
print(r'\end{center}')
\end{pycode}

\end{document}
```

When I hit the build and view button though, everything hangs, and the log displays the following errors (line numbers correspond to the file `pythontex.sty`):

```
line 284: Use of \@xs@StrSubstitute@@ doesn't match its definition. \StrSubstitute{\pytx@jobname}{"}{}
line 284: Use of \\lstinline doesn't match its definition. \StrSubstitute{\pytx@jobname}{"}{}
line 284: Undefined control sequence. \StrSubstitute{\pytx@jobname}{"}{}
line 284: Undefined control sequence. \StrSubstitute{\pytx@jobname}{"}{}
line 284: Undefined control sequence. \StrSubstitute{\pytx@jobname}{"}{}
line 284: Undefined control sequence. \StrSubstitute{\pytx@jobname}{"}{}
line 284: Undefined control sequence. \StrSubstitute{\pytx@jobname}{"}{}
line 284: Undefined control sequence. \StrSubstitute{\pytx@jobname}{"}{}
line 284: Use of \@ doesn't match its definition. \StrSubstitute{\pytx@jobname}{"}{}
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me. Is it only if you compile from the editor or form the console too?

Comment: @TeXnician Does it work fine for you from within TeXstudio? I have only tried to compile from the editor, not the console.

Comment: I have tried from within the console and from TeXstudio. It works.

Comment: @TeXnician could I see how you have set up things in your editor (assuming it is TeXstudio?)

Comment: I've said it's TeXstudio. I've one custom command which looks like this: `txs:///pdflatex | pythontex %.tex | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///biber | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view-pdf-internal
`

Comment: @TeXnician Using what you're using makes it work for me too! Before, I was using `txs:///pdflatex | txs:///pythontex | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///biber | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view-pdf-internal`, where `txs:///pythontex` was a reference to a custom command (see main body of my question), which was an alias for `pythontex.exe %.tex`. So, that doesn't work, but changing the custom command so that it aliases`pythontex %.tex` (without the `.exe`) makes everything work fine! I wonder what difference the `.exe` makes...

Comment: Because it's pythontex.py!

Comment: @TeXnician but I am referencing a `.exe` in particular; that's what is copied into my System folder (see PythonTeX documentation); when I go into a console, I have to typing in `pythontex` or `pythontex.exe` gives me the same output. Also, if it was a `.py` we were running, we'd have to type `python pythontex.py`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59859/discussion-between-texnician-and-user89).

Comment: In TeXstudio, for user command name typically I use the following form: `pythontex:pythontex` (although your form may be acceptable too)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments