# Setting conda environment for pythontex in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, python, pythontex

I am using Texstudio with a build configuration based on this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373000/how-to-configure-texstudio-to-use-pythontex) in order to run PythonTex and embed python code into my documents. This worked and I was able to use the `\begin{pycode}` and `\end{pycode}` successfully.

However the libraries I want to use are in a dedicated conda environment and not in the main system python. I added the `--interpreter` argument to my build in Texstudio such that it uses the interpreter from that environment. My build command looks like this in Texstudio:

```
txs:///compile | pythontex %.tex --interpreter "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\wps_env36\python.exe" | txs:///compile | txs:///view
```

Simple commands like `print('hello')` will work. However as soon as I try to import libraries which I know exist in this environment it returns an error. This indicates to me that although the interpreter is correctly set, other parameters necessary for the functioning of the conda environment are not.

How do I activate a conda environment such that it becomes the one pythontex is using within TexStudio?

Answer (score 3):

You can activate the conda environment (`activate.bat`) and chain it (`&&`) with running `pythontex` using:

```
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Scripts\activate.bat" "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\wps_env36\python.exe" && pythontex %.tex
```

By the way, it is generally not recommended to pollute the build chain with raw commands like you did. It's better to save this as a user command, then call it during your `Build & View` call.

[image]

---

To show that pythontex is in the correct environment, (on a bare test environment with `pygments` installed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}
\begin{pycode}
import sys
print(sys.version)
\end{pycode}
hello world
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

whereas my base python environment has version 3.6.7.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me, but there is a good explanation [here](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/165) of the formatting that is needed to properly activate the environment and use the correct interpreter. Some limitations of `pythontex` working in envs are also noted.