# Getting PythonTex to work with TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, pythontex

I cannot get PythonTex to fully work with TexStudio. I'm having a nightmare with this and solved many issues, including activating the conda base, mkl-service library clashes, and TexStudio command paths. My environment variables also needed to be fixed to include the Anaconda library binaries in the search path. The remaining issue I cannot solve after two days is generating plots through PythonTex. The error appears as: 
*"This application failed to start because it could not find or load Qt platform plugin"windows".*
A native Windows cmd has the same problem so I do not think PythonTex is at fault. I think the problem is with importing libraries outside of the python core into TexStudio.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}
\begin{pycode}
import sys
print(sys.version)
\end{pycode}
\end{document}
```

This prints: `3.7.6 (default, Jan 8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]`

Here is a nonworking example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}
\begin{pylabblock}
rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('font', family='serif')
rc('font', size=10.0)
rc('legend', fontsize=10.0)
rc('font', weight='normal')
x = linspace(0, 10)
figure(figsize=(4, 2.5))
plot(x, sin(x), label='$\sin(x)$')
xlabel(r'$x\mathrm{-axis}$')
ylabel(r'$y\mathrm{-axis}$')
legend(loc='lower right')
savefig('myplot.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
\end{pylabblock}
\end{document}
```

I have done the following to try and rectify the problem:

- Activated conda base
- Did `conda install mkl-service`
- Tried piping conda activation as per [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463918/setting-conda-environment-for-pythontex-in-texstudio)
- Verified that there is no clash of MKL libraries using `where libiomp5md.dll` as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778066/importerror-dll-load-failed-when-importing-numpy-installed-in-conda-virtual-env) and [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/835)
- Verified the python code in Spyder and in the native cmd prompt
- Tried adding the QT_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable

Unfortunately, the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463918/setting-conda-environment-for-pythontex-in-texstudio) has not worked for me either. Any help much appreciated.

System:

- Windows10
- TexStudio 2.12.6
- Conda 4.8.2
- PythonTex 0.17

Comment: Having so much trouble with it as you do, I would recommend to move to use TeXworks and drop `Anaconda` distribution and use pure python (and install packages with `pip`). I found no benefit for using Anaconda over python itself ... You example works for my setting on Win10, TeXworks in TeXlive2019, python 3.8 64bit and PythonTeX 0.17

Comment: @TomášKruliš I had been outside `conda` before, but needed pymc3 which is a nightmare of dependencies - the great strength of `conda`. Shouldn't this _just work_?!

Comment: Yes, it certainly should. I am not that proficient in python (beginner programmer, I only dare to say). As not that pro, I dont se any nightmares - not using `pymc3`, I am using almost all its listed dependencies (except for `Theano`) and I have no problem. For me is a surprise, that you have to set-up an envinment variable (?connected to `qt`?) to make work a machine learning module. Doesnt seem right. I dare to say that `conda` has its own problems with dependencies managing, think I read somewhere it has trouble to keep up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying lots of things, including the suggestions from [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1270), I have found just one solution to solving the Qt issue: ***start TexStudio from the Anaconda prompt***

Even though the environment variables are the same (can check using `os.environ` in python and easily print output to LaTeX file using the `pyconsole` environment), this seems to work. Presumably there is a different 'priority' given to paths in the environment?

**EDIT**

I dug into this a bit further to try and understand why this works. Using `!set` from a python prompt reveals the environment variables currently active. Looking at the `PATH` variable, it can be seen that Anaconda adds its paths to the top of the path list (even though they are already further down the list as inhereited from the system environment variables). So *the order of the environment variables matters* as the environment will stop at the first instance of whatever command it is looking for. So the fix is to **put the Anaconda paths to the top of my environment variables**. This means I can run TexStudio from the usual shortcut and the correct paths are used!